# How to call native Listview Activity from phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, listview, cordova

I have a Listview activity which is written in native Java code. I want to call this activity in PhoneGap HTML.

Is there any way to display the native listview like the html view?

I want to do this because native Java Listview's are much faster and efficient than PhoneGap List View.